# Serialize all the fields from the response Android Studio?

Tags: android, api, serialization

Just one doubt. An API is giving me the following response:

[image: API response]

As you can see it gives back a lot of fields and values. But since I just want, for example, the name and the released date, could I just Serialize those values that I want? Or it would be needed to declare everything even when it's not used on my app ?

```
    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer idGame;
    @SerializedName("slug")
    private String slugGame;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String nameGame;
    @SerializedName("description")
    private String descriptionGame;
    @SerializedName("released")
    private String releasedGame;
    @SerializedName("background_image")
    private String imageGame;
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

No need to declare all.
The following will be enough for your case.

```
@SerializedName("name")
private String nameGame;
@SerializedName("released")
private String releasedGame;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I've try searching for this response but I couldn't find anyone who said that you have to or that is not necessary! They would only serialized all values.

Comment: Usually in the tutorials they declare all. But in my apps I only declare the values I need.

Answer (score 0):

No need all. Just define some `key` you want to use. 
But in another case. `API` define all key to use at another screen (1 API use at many screen). If you want reuse this class, you can define it before.

Hope it helpful. Thanks!